# Python pandas dataframe.stack() and convert to Json to create a dataTable.js

Tags: python, json, pandas

I have this code

```
#Initial dataFrame

  Coupon Value Face Value  Percent - PV of FACE  Present Value Rate - SAIR
0            8       1000              9.619702      96.197019         .34
```

```
df_pvBondsStacked = df_pvBonds.stack()
                    print(df_pvBondsStacked)
```

prints at terminal as below

```
0  Coupon Value                 8
   Face Value                1000
   Percent - PV of FACE    9.6197
   Present Value           96.197
   Rate - SAIR                .34
```

I have referred the official pandas docs here - https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_json.html

and coded as below -

```
df_pvBondsStacked.columns = ['Col_1','Col_2']
# this line of code up here - does nothing ?
data = data = json.loads(df_pvBondsStacked.to_json(orient='split'))
dict_json = {}
dict_json['data_json'] = data
print(dict_json)
```

terminal prints as below -

```
{'data_json': {'index': [[0, 'Coupon Value'], [0, 'Face Value'], [0, 'Percent - PV of FACE'], [0, 'Present Value'], [0, 'Rate - SAIR']], 'data': ['8', '1000', 9.619701877, 96.1970187705, '.34'], 'name': None}}
```

Also if i pass params for orient , .to_json(orient='') - "values" , "index",and "table" ,  i get ERROR printed in terminal -

```
Error = json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting ':' delimiter: line 1 column 7 (char 6)
```

My Question -- How to create Column Headers for the data frame = `df_pvBondsStacked` , as i dont think i can have **valid JSON** to pass to the dataTables.js , without creating Column Headers ?

Comment: My mistake did not read properly - the docs clearly mention -- Stacking a dataframe with a single level column axis returns a Series:

Answer (score 0):

My mistake the docs clearly mention --

> Stacking a dataframe with a single level column axis returns a Series:

```
df_pvBondsStacked = df_pvBondsStacked.to_frame()
df_pvBondsStacked.reset_index(inplace=True)
df_pvBondsStacked.columns = ['Index','Col_Labels','Values_Numeric']
```

further tweaks required ...